# Verificar se array é associativo em uma classe

Tags: php, array, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma classe em que preciso fazer certas verificações em um array, como por exemplo, verificar se ele é associativo ou indexado. Sei que não existe função nativa no PHP que faça isso, então poderia utilizar o exemplo abaixo.

```
function isAssoc($arr)
{
    return array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1);
}
```

Exemplo tirado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/how-to-check-if-php-array-is-associative-or-sequential).

Mas, como estou trabalhando com orientação a objetos e gostaria de fazer as coisas do jeito certo, sei que:

1. Não é bacana criar uma lista de funções em um arquivo global "faz tudo".
2. A classe onde estou executando a verificação não deve saber como devo fazer a verificação, apenas verificar, assim uma *clousure* também não seria uma boa ideia.
3. Como quero que a minha classe seja de utilização mais simples não vejo sentido injetar uma dependência para uma classe que trate arrays na assinatura do método, queria apenas verificar o tal array, como uma função nativa faz.

Em resumo, queria implementar algo como o código abaixo, porém do jeito certo:

```
public function __construct($name, $content = null, $attributes= null)  
{
    if(is_assoc($content){
        // 
    }
    else{
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: Sugiro criar um classe *helper* com método(s) estático(s): `ArrayHelper::isAssoc()`

Answer (score 1):

Pensei aqui em algumas maneiras para resolver esse problema.

A primeira é utilizar uma função global. Nem tudo em sua aplicação precisa ser orientado a objeto ou só existe um jeito certo de fazer as coisas. Para esse caso não vejo problema disso ser uma função global se realmente fizer sentido.

Outra forma é criar uma [*trait*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php) e inserir ela em sua classe, algo assim:

```
trait ArrayUtils 
{
    function isAssoc(array $arr)
    {
        return array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1);
    }
}

class MyClass 
{
    use ArrayUtils;

    public function __construct($name, array $content = [], $attributes= null)  
    {
        if($this->is_assoc($content){

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Se possível acho interessante garantir que o argumento enviado é um array empregando o [*type hinting*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.typehinting.php), assim é possível evitar algumas verificações extras nos seus métodos.